# How can I get Cookie value by declare a Local variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

When I Debug this line it shows like

```
Request.Cookies["Login"]["Username"].ToString()="Raju"
```

But when I declare a String type variable like

```
 String ss;
 ss = Request.Cookies["Login"]["Username"].ToString();
```

After debugging ss shows like

```
ss=null;
```

why?

Comment: `Request.Cookies["Login"]["Username"].ToString()="Raju"` isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: This line like as Request.Cookies["Login"]["Username"].ToString(); But when debugging it shows the value of 'Request.Cookies["Login"] ["Username"].ToString()="raju"

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    UserAccount u = new UserAccount();
    if (Request.Cookies["Login"] != null)
    {
        u.UserName = Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["UserName"]; 
    }
    return View(u);
}
```

Comment: Please do not provide code-only answers. Instead, add an explanation how and why the code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can define like this

```
String ss;
ss = Request.Cookies["Login"].Values["UserName"];
```